# How to load third party libraries using Require.js in Angular.js project

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, sbt, webjars, datamaps

Really don't understand how to load third party libraries using Require.js in Angular.js project

For example 'topojson' is defined, but 'datamap' is undefined in this case.

Datamap from here https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/dist/datamaps.world.js

Topojson from here https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/topojson.js

Angular app.js:

```
'use strict';
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'angular': ['../lib/angularjs/angular'],
        'angular-route': ['../lib/angular-route/angular-route'],
        'angular-resource': ['../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource'],
        'angular-animate': ['../lib/angular-animate/angular-animate'],
        'datamap':['../app/dense/world-view/datamaps.world'],
        'topojson':['../app/dense/world-view/topojson'],
        'lodash': ['../lib/lodash/lodash'],
        'd3': ['../lib/d3js/d3']
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-route': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-resource': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-animate': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'd3': {
            exports: 'd3'
        },
        'topojson': {
            deps: ['d3'],
            exports: 'topojson'
        },
        'datamaps': {
            deps: ['d3', 'topojson'],
            exports: 'datamaps'
        },
        'lodash': {
            exports: 'lodash'
        }
    }
});

require(
    [
        'angular',
        'topojson',
        'datamap',
        'angular-route',
        'angular-resource',
        'angular-animate',
        'lodash',
        'd3'
    ],
    function (angular, topojson, datamap) {

        console.log("topojson", topojson);
        console.log("datamap", datamap); // is undefined

        angular.module('myApp', [
            'myApp.graph',
            'myApp.node',
            'myApp.dense',
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngRoute'])
            .config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/login'
                });
            })
        ;

        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myAppId"), ['myApp']);

    });
```

Some of the Angular controllers:

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function (angular) {

    angular
        .module('myApp.dense', ['ngRoute'])

        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/dense', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/app/dense/dense.html',
                controller: 'DenseCtrl'
            });
        }])

        .controller('DenseCtrl', function ($scope) {

            var map = new Datamap({
                scope: 'world',
                element: document.getElementById("someId"),
                projection: 'mercator',
                height: 500,
                fills: {
                    defaultFill: '#f0af0a',
                    lt50: 'rgba(0,244,244,0.9)',
                    gt50: 'red'
                },

                data: {
                }
            });
        })
    ;

});
```

In my angular controller  new Datamap(...) says 'ReferenceError: Datamap is not defined'

This is not the only case.
Same for most external JS libraries.

I am running Angular project on top of Scala and SBT with WebJars, so Require.js is the only way how to load all that stuff.

Comment: Is it making a request for the Datamaps source code in the 'Network' tab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any imports except for `angular` in your RequireJS module (the second snippet in your question). You need to add your other dependencies, such as `datamap`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like in 'Datamap' object does not initialize, line 12535:

https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/dist/datamaps.world.js#L12535

```
  // expose library
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    d3 = require('d3');
    topojson = require('topojson');
    module.exports = Datamap;
  }
  else if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "datamaps", ["require", "d3", "topojson"], function(require) {
      d3 = require('d3');
      topojson = require('topojson');

      return Datamap;
    });
    // window.Datamap = window.Datamaps = Datamap;  // hack
  }
  else {
    window.Datamap = window.Datamaps = Datamap;
  }
```

Now it works for me.
Added that line after define:

```
window.Datamap = window.Datamaps = Datamap;  // hack
```

and used require block inside Angular controller:

```
 requirejs(["datamaps"], function () {
      // draw map here new Datamap({...})
 };
```